# Tricky code: std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

Tags: c++, c++11

I have here a very dirty piece of code (it is very tricky code to torture students)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

    cout << "MagicIF" << endl;
    cout << "-------" << endl << endl;

    int a(7), b(42), c(1);
    cout << "a = " << a << endl << "b = " << b << endl << "c = " << c << endl << endl;

    if (a < b)
        if (c > a)
            cout << "a ist kleiner als b und kleiner als c." << endl;
    else
        cout << "a ist grösser oder gleich b." << endl;

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The first line is the exciting part:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
```

When you start the code as he is, the "if / else" construct will not work properly. When you set some braces so that "if / else" is working, it is possible that the line above create an endless loop.

So, how is this possible? What is this line exactly doing?

Comment: [`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) is well documented. Nothing special with it. You're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Upvoters mind to explain? As is the question is clearly off topic.

Comment: I don't see any trickiness whatsoever.  If setting the global locale that way causes an infinite loop, I expect that the runtime in question (especially, that particular localization) is buggy.  I'm surprised the code compiles at all given the 'ö' char in the last string literal.

Comment: Eh... Do you mean that `system("pause");` creates an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks for your help! the first line of code (std::locale) is creating an endless loop as soon as I change some code in the if/else region.

Comment: did you ever figure out whats happening with std::locale:? I also got very weird behaviour in a program where I used it

Answer (score 4):

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
```

is ok, it sets the global locale to some default locale.

Your real problem is with matching the else to the proper if. Your code *really* is

```
if (a < b)
    if (c > a)
        cout << "a ist kleiner als b und kleiner als c." << endl;
    else
        cout << "a ist grösser oder gleich b." << endl;
```

Spot the difference?

You might want to add some `{}` to get the correct if-else pairing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Of course I knew how to use {} ;) The problem (at least at my system) As soon as I change code in the region of if/else the first line of code (with std::locale) is creating an endless loop!